# How to create search button for existing code which execute search on enter press? php/javascript/mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have a website which someone else have been coding for me and i'm trying to understand how to change a simple thing.

I am not webdeveloper but on the last days I got familiar a bit with php, mysql and javascript (i'm familiar with java).

****The Question:****
On my website I have search form which works **without** search button (search function works on enter press or when choosing from autocomplete). How do i change it to work only with search button ?

The web developed with framework called CodeIgniter.

This is how controller looks like:

```
public function searchGym()
{
if($_POST)
{
$gym_name=$_POST['gym_name'];
$gym_name=trim($gym_name," ");  
$data['details']=$this->user_model->getGymByName($gym_name);
$data['gym_name']=$gym_name;
$this->load->view('he/searched_gym',$data);
}
}
```

This is how model look like:

```
 public function getGymByName($query_string)
 {
    $query_string=mysql_real_escape_string($query_string);
    $query=$this->db->query("select * from gym_members_table where member_title like '%$query_string%'");
    return $query->result_array();
 }
</code>
```

And this is the index.php search form :

```
            <div class="search-home">

              <input type="text" onkeypress="gymhandle(event);" class="form-control gym_search" id="gym" name="gym" placeholder="
Search by Name
              " >
              <div class="autosuggest1"></div>
              <div class="autosuggest"></div>

            </div>


  <script>


function settextbox(rval){

  $('.autosuggest').hide();

    $('#gym').val(rval);
    $('#gym_search2').val(rval);
    searchGymByName(rval);

  }



$(document).ready(function(){



  $('.autosuggest').hide();

  $('#gym').keyup(function(e)
    { 



       var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);

    // do nothing if it's an arrow key
    if(code == 37 || code == 38 || code == 39 || code == 40 || code==13) {
        return;
    }


     var search_term = $(this).val();


     var getdata = { 'search_term': search_term};

       if(search_term!=''){

       $.ajax({ 

          url: "<?php echo site_url('hebrew/searchGymAuto');?>",

          data: getdata,

          type: 'POST',

          success: function(data){

          $('.autosuggest').show();

          $('.autosuggest').html(data);

          }

          });

       }

       else

       {

        $('.autosuggest').hide();

       }

  });



});

$('.autosuggest').hide();



function searchGymByName(rval)

{
$('.autosuggest').hide();
var gym_name=rval;


$.ajax({

  url:"<?php echo site_url();?>hebrew/searchGym",

  type: "POST",

  data:{gym_name: gym_name},

  success:function(res){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
    $("#ajax-map").hide();

    $("#city").val('');

    $("#city1").val('');

     $("#ajax-page-hide").show();

    $("#ajax-page-hide").html(res);

  } 

});

}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: $('#gym').keyup(function(e) is the function causing it to load automatically.Use this function when sommeone presses the search button

Comment: Thanks, whenever I'll manage to disable it.. how do i call this function when the button pressed? this is my code for the button: <input type="submit" name="searchgymbutton" value="Search!">

Comment: Remove $('#gym').keyup(function(e) and add $('[name="searchgymbutton"]').click(function(e) in its place

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the enter keypress on those fields like this:

```
$('.gym_search').keypress(function(e){
    if ( e.which == 13 ) return false;
    //or...
    if ( e.which == 13 ) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hi I tried it (see the new code) but it didn't cancelled it.. any ideas why?

Comment: <code> $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.autosuggest').hide();
  $('#gym').keyup(function(e)
    { 
       var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);
    
 //cancel enter 
 $('.gym_search').keypress(function(e){
    if ( e.which == 13 ) return false;
 } </code>

Comment: add code == 13 in your <code>$('#gym').keyup(function(e){}</code>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the id attribute from the search input field, and place **id="gym"** on the search button. And then in **$('#gym').click(function(e)** [note: 'click' instead of 'keyup'], change the search_term to

```
var search_term = $("gym_search").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove onkeypress event from text box. Add ajax call for search in java script function and call that function on button click event